# Execute grep on remote site to detect running process

Tags: java, jar, terminal, grep

I have searched all over but found no luck yet, I am using linux ubuntu flavour and need to know that how can I check that whether the java jar file is running at remote end or not using pgrep. As the pgrep -f "someProcess" returns the Process ID.

Note: Both systems are linux based, and I only need to done it through terminal. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Ant to do this.

I can't remember which task I used unfortunately....

But we executed a command or script remotely using an ant task.

I think we used [`ExecTask`](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Copy.html).

Notice you can specify an output file.

You can read that to process the output of your command.

Ant is pretty awesome in that anything you can do with an Ant script, you can do with Java.

And it's a lot easier than you'd think.

I believe [this is a good starting pont](http://ant.apache.org/manual/antexternal.html) to learn how to do it.

Here is the [Javadoc overview page](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/overview-summary.html) for the Ant classes.

Here are some more links to helpful Javadoc pages:

- [`Project`](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/Project.html)
- [`Task`](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/Task.html) (the base class for all Ant tasks)
- [`SSHExec task`](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/ssh/SSHExec.html) (looks like this is what you want)
- [`ExecTask`](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/ExecTask.html)
- [`Copy` task](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Copy.html) (this is a nice simple one for "*Hello, World*" purposes
- [`FTP` task](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/net/FTP.html)

I'm sure there other ways, but as they say [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/antexternal.html) Ant makes things very easy for you.

Comment: "Up Vote and Marked for Answer" for your good reply. I did it through sshexec. Will learn ANT in more detail from now on. Thanks once again.

Comment: That was quick! Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of one way to do this.

Assuming you have servers A and B, A performs the process check on B. You can use ssh and setup [no-password login from A->B](http://rcsg-gsir.imsb-dsgi.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/documents/internet/node31.html) and use command below:

```
ssh root@12.34.56.78 "pgrep [whatever keyword]"
```

You'll get the same result as executing the command on B.

Comment: Thanks buddy, It worked! as for my requirement it's perfect. Up vote for you also.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [plink.exe](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/putty/putty-0.57/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) to do this.  You can pass commands to plink in the form of a .txt file input.